# Extracting words from given string and its appropriate values

Tags: java, regex

Amod applies for multiple engineering entrance examination and after submitting application he gets messages as below:

```
Application 1: Hi Amod. Your registration number is AX1234 and hallticket number is XC876
Application 2:Hi Amod. Your hallticket is AX1234 and registration number is XC876
Application 3:Hi Amod. Your hallticket and registration are AX1234 and XC876
Application 4:Hi Amod. AX1234 and XC876 are Your hallticket and registration
```

Now we need to develop a java program which will extract and print hall ticket and registration number from a given string. In string, order of registration number and hall ticket number can be changed. We need to develop a program which will give hall ticket number and registration number without bothering about order of words.

SOlution till I tried:

I tried to find indexes of required words i.e. Registration, hallticket and two aplhanumeric words.

```
String inputString = "Hi Amod. AX1234 and XC876 are Your hallticket and registration";
String inputStringArray[] = inputString.split("\\s+");
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String regex = "^(?=[^\\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (int i = 0; i < inputStringArray.length; i++) {
    switch (inputStringArray[i].toLowerCase()) {
        case "registration":
            map.put(inputStringArray[i].toLowerCase(), i);
            break;
        case "hallticket":
            map.put(inputStringArray[i].toLowerCase(), i);
            break;

    }

    if (inputStringArray[i].matches(regex)) {
        map.put(inputStringArray[i], i);
    }

}
System.out.println(map);
```

It prints bwlow output:

```
{AX1234=2, XC876=4, hallticket=7, registration=9}
```

Now I am confused, how to relate two alphanumeric to hallticket and registration. Can some one help me??

Comment: i really don't understand your question, can you please explain more?

Comment: In simple words, the term registration and hallticket can appear anywhere in given string. You need to extract what is value of registration number and hall ticket .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String inputString = "Hi Amod. Your registration number is AX1234 and hallticket number is XC876";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2}\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
    String [] values = new String[2];
    int i=0;
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        values[i++] = m.group();
    } 
    if(inputString.indexOf("registration")<inputString.indexOf("hallticket")){
        map.put("registration", values[0]);
        map.put("hallticket", values[1]);
    }
    else{
        map.put("registration", values[1]);
        map.put("hallticket", values[0]);
    }
    for(Entry e: map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(e.getKey() +" : "+e.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eritrean. I implemented the same logic and it is working fine for all types of input string. Just I changed regex to satisfy any length of alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

The simple type is

`feature is string`

Where feature can be `hallticket` or `registration number` it is trivial to extract this using regex.

The little more complex one is

`feature and feature` combined with `string and string`.

Extract all substring in the form of `[a-zA-Z0-9]+ and [a-zA-Z0-9]+` one of the matched ones will give the relative position and the other will give the values.

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the job.

Try looking at the ordering in the sentence. If the word "hallticket" comes before "registration", then most likely the hallticket code will be earlier in the sentence than the registration code. Just make sure that your regex fits.

That works for your example sentences and probably for every plausible Engish sentence giving the codes...